# Automatically close comments on PAGES older than X days

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I would like to disable comments on pages in WordPress after time lapse just like I can do for posts / articles using the Settings > Discussions.

After hours of Googling, I came across this link 
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-stop-comments-on-your-wordpress-posts/

...that has this code that I added to my child functions.php:

```
function check_comments_open() {
    global $post;

    // if the post comment status is not open then no need to worry
    if ( $post->comment_status != 'open' ) return false;

    // if not closing comments on old posts then also don't worry
    if ( !get_option('close_comments_for_old_posts') ) return $post->comment_status;

    // calculate the age (in days) of the post
    $post_date = date_create( $post->post_date );
    $today = date_create();
    $age = date_interval_format( date_diff( $post_date , $today ) , '%a' );

    // if the post is older than the 'close after x days' then close comments
    if ( $age > get_option('close_comments_days_old') ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'comments_open' , 'check_comments_open' );
```

**This does not work** (using a customized twenty eleven theme).  Readers are still given the opportunity to add a comment on all pages where comments are allowed.  Not all pages have comments.  Just the ones that do, and that have actual comments on them, we'd like to be able to keep the comments, but stop new ones from getting published.

Thanks.

Comment: That code depends on a number of options. Have you set these as well on the posts?

Comment: I was turning the post discussion settings off and on to check out the differences - and realized I hadn't turned it back on after saving the code to the functions page.  It now works.  D'oh!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disable Comments on older posts]

1. Go to your posts page
2. Expand the screen options section
3. Change the options so you’ve got a decent number of posts on screen
4. Apply the screen options change
5. Select all posts
6. Choose “edit” in the bulk options drop down.
7. Set “comments” to “do not allow” (to disable commenting)
8. Set “pings” to “do not allow” (to disable pingbacks)
9. Click on the “update” button.

If you didn’t set your screen options high enough to show all posts, then you’ll need to repeat the above for “page 2″ of all posts (and 3… 4.. etc)

Turning off pings helps reduce the amount of spam coming into your WordPress installation, even if you are using Disqus or akismet.

Comment: Really helpful about the pings - but I didn't want to disallow/unallow comments on posts as much as I wanted to disable on pages and only after 7 days had passed on by.  Thanks!

Comment: see this article [Automatically close comments on articles older than some days](http://www.clickonf5.org/6322/automatically-close-comments-older-posts-avoid-spam-wordpress-blog/)

Comment: also see this article i thing its useful for you [WordPress: Disable comments on old posts](http://benohead.com/wordpress-disable-comments-on-old-posts/)